# Specify Vector of Maximum Values for Tensorflow Random Uniform

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I need to generate a vector of examples where each element in the vector is drawn randomly from a distribution with a different maximum value. The maximum values are contained in a different vector. I tried using tensorflow's random.uniform function, but it appears that only one maximum value can be specified. Here is my non-vectorized code:

```
f = tf.random.uniform([num_examples], minval=0, maxval=v, dtype=tf.int32)
for i in range(num_examples):
   f0 = tf.random.uniform([num_examples], minval=0, maxval=v-f[i], dtype=tf.int32)
```

Trying to specify a vector of maximum values (code below):

```
f = tf.random.uniform([num_examples], minval=0, maxval=v, dtype=tf.int32)
f0 = tf.random.uniform([num_examples], minval=0, maxval=v-f, dtype=tf.int32)
```

returns an error because tensorflow's random.uniform only accepts one maximum value, rather than a vector of them. Do you have any advice about how to vectorize this?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate distribution with `0..1` range and multiply result by a vector with the required range:

```py
> tf.random.uniform([10], minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32) * tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], dtype=tf.float32)

<tf.Tensor: shape=(10,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0.48777616, 0.22365022, 1.5342396 , 2.8297348 , 3.088411  ,
       0.36669016, 3.0236297 , 6.178155  , 4.1499534 , 7.2168493 ],
      dtype=float32)>
```